# Prove, a^2+b^2=c^2,there exists only 1 case such that a,b,c are consecutive non negative integers(3,4,5)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, number-theory

I want to prove, $a^2+b^2=c^2$,there exists only 1 case such that a,b,c are consecutive non-negative integers(3,4,5).

I have no clue to prove this lemma. Please help me to prove this lemma.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is purely mathematical and has no computational content. It should be asked on [math.se].

Comment: Hint: assume that the solutions are $n$, $n+1$ and $n+2$.

Comment: ... and note that the restriction to non-negative integers rules out the alternative solution $(a,b,c)=(-1,0,1)$

Comment: It is not a lemma. A lemma is a theorem that is not important itself, but is just a building block for the theorem you are really interested in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$n^2 + (n + 1)^2 = (n + 2)^2 \Rightarrow n^2 + n^2 + 2n + 1 = n^2 + 4n + 4 \Rightarrow 2n^2 2n + 1 = n^2 + 4n + 4 \Rightarrow n^2 - 2n - 3 = 0 \Rightarrow n = -1, 3$

Therefore, 3 is the only plausible solution.